# OpenCV for iOS sudoku grabber

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, opencv, sudoku

I'm following this tutorial
http://aishack.in/tutorials/sudoku-grabber-with-opencv-detection/
But it's not fot the iOS.
some methods described there can be used, but the floodfill (used as cvFloodFill) is no longer an int. it's a void

I'm trying to get the size of the biggest blob, It's pretty much the part i'm missing. this for loops and the floodfill.

is there a good way of doing it?

I thought about the cvBlob library, but I just can't get it to compile for mac.. tried many ways....

EDIT: After arkiaz's answer, moved to a new question:

[openCV cvContourArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232080/opencv-cvcontourarea)

Thanks!

Comment: The first link was dead - updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `floodfill` you can use `findcontour` to find biggest blob.

Do as follows:

1) Apply adaptive threshold, some erosion and dilation etc ( as mentioned in aishack)

2) Find contours using [`findcontours`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=cvfindcontours#findcontours)

3) Use [`contourarea`](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=cvfindcontours#contourarea) to find area of each contour

5) Select the one with max. area. That will be the sudoku box. Then continue as given in aishack.in

For me, this method worked faster than floodfill method

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and report back!

Comment: Hi, I edited my original post with a problem regarding ur answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Better undo back to your previous question, since you already accepted my answer ( it is equal to closing this session.) Ask it as a seperate question. that is more better.